# Hide a dynamic element function on.('hide')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with the following function. I am dynamically creating a bootstrap modal (regular div), and I want to attach a function I pass trough a variable (witch works fine) and run it on on.("hide"), but instead it fires as soon as the modal is opened ( $(modal).on('hide', windowclose_function ); ). Is there something I`m missing?

Thanks

```
function openModalFromUrl(modal_url, close_function = function(){}) {

    var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content"); 

    $.ajax({
        data: { 
            '_token': token,
        },
        url: modal_url,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(html) {

            // create a new modal div
            var modal = document.createElement("div");
            $(modal).addClass('modal fade');
            $(modal).attr( "role", "dialog" );

            $('body').append(modal);

            // place response in the modal
            $(modal).html(html)

            // open the modal
            $(modal).modal('show'); 

            // THIS FIRES IMMEDIATELY
            $(modal).on('hide', window[close_function]() );

        },

        error: function() {
            bootbox.alert('Error');  
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$(modal).on('hide', close_function);`?

Comment: `$(modal).on('hide', window[close_function]);` remove `()` just pass the  function reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The issue is in this line :-**

```js
$(modal).on('hide', window[close_function]() );
```

**Change it to :-**

```js
$(modal).on('hide', window[close_function] );
```

**Explanation :-**

In JavaScript when we provide a function as a reference, we use it's name without any parenthesis

> i.e. 'my_func' not 'my_func()'

As 'my_func()' give the result of the function as reference not the function itself.

So just remove the parenthesis and your problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... but it does not seem to work... here is what I have changed adn tested now, and it wont seem to call the function on hide at all (I have tried with 'hide' and 'hidden.bs.modal' events)

`var test_function = function() {
                    alert('aaa');
                }

                // reset the function on close
                $(modal).on('hide.bs.modal', test_function );
`

Comment: Take a look here.... https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal_event_hide&stacked=h

If it still doesn't work... then please check your bootstrap js & css files.

Comment: This was the issue, and the fact that the div is dynamically created so I had to use 
`$('body').on('hide.bs.modal', modal, window[close_function] );`
Marking this as the answer, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) you should use `hidden.bs.modal` event. Also no need in checking the `window` object for the function, just pass it.

```js
$('#myModal').modal('show');

var close_function = function () {
  console.log('closed');
}

$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', close_function);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="modal fade" id='myModal' abindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer... The problem is that the function that can have different names.I use the button to pass the function name to the modal (ex. data-callback="refresh_list") , and I want to call that function

Comment: but you pass it to openModalFromUrl, your local parammeter there is always close_function

Comment: I have a dynamic button that opens the openModalFromUrl function. And this button has data-url that is the url of the ajax modal, and a data-close_function that is the name of the function that should run when the modal closes. I dont know if I can pass the function reference from the button?
`
    $('body').on('click', '.modal_url', function(){
            openModalFromUrl( $(this).data('url'), $(this).data('close_function') );    
      
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all for your answers. I have found the solution. 
As the modals were dynamically generated i had to change the call to:

```
 $('body').on('hide.bs.modal', modal, window[close_function] );
```

Now it works like a charm. Thanks again to everyone!